# Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIColor' and 'Int'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**i am learning video app and my tutorial was write in swift 2.3 But i am practicing on xcode 8 and swift 3
now i have his problem : Note : this code is in appdelegate.swift

```
extension UIColor {
    static func rgb(displayP3Red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(displayP3Red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue, 255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

i get this error :
Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIColor' and 'Int'

Comment: Where do you have `red` defined?

Comment: `red/255` should be `displayP3Red/255`, and `blue, 255` should be `blue/255`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension should be like this:

```
extension UIColor {
    static func rgb(displayP3Red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: displayP3Red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very very very much    you are very nice human